# Any way to force fread() of data.table not to stop on empty lines?

Tags: r, data.table

(question is not relevant anymore, since new version of `data.table` of 25-NOV-2016 - see accepted answer below)

So, I have a table with some empty lines in the middle. When I try to open it with `fread`, it stops, saying `Stopped reading at empty line 10006, but text exists afterwards (discarded)`. Is there any way to avoid this without changing the data file?

Comment: What OS are you on? On *nix you can just combine with a command line command to filter out the empty lines.

Comment: well, I am on Windows. Of course it should be possible to find some similar command here to do the same filtering, but I am still curious is there any smarter way...

Comment: I think the answer is "no".  You should probably submit a feature request: https://r-forge.r-project.org/search/?type_of_search=artifact&group_id=240&atid=978&words=fread&Search=Search .  If you install the cygwin tools you can `egrep -v ^$` to strip empty lines ...

Comment: @BenBolker I have installed the `GoW` ( [**GNU on Windows**](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki) ) package which I really like as it's very simple to install and *very* lightweight. And includes [**many**](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki/executables_list) of the most the common `*nix` command lines tools.

Comment: As per the help file for `fread()` (1.8.10), the Details section, this is the intended behavior. If the data is relatively small, you can always read it in as a text string, massage it with R's regexp functions to remove the empty lines and then pass the string as the `input=` argument to `fread()`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Version 1.9.8 of data.table](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md#changes-in-v198--on-cran-25-nov-2016), released 25-NOV-2016, has a new `blank.lines.skip` option to skip blank lines.

```
text <- "1,a\n\n2,b\n3,c\n4,a\n\n5,b\n\n6,c"

library(data.table)
fread(text)
##    V1 V2
## 1:  2  b
## 2:  3  c
## 3:  4  a
## Warning message:
## In fread("1,a\n\n2,b\n3,c\n4,a\n\n5,b\n\n6,c") :
##   Stopped reading at empty line 6 but text exists afterwards (discarded): 5,b

fread(text, blank.lines.skip=TRUE)
##    V1 V2
## 1:  1  a
## 2:  2  b
## 3:  3  c
## 4:  4  a
## 5:  5  b
## 6:  6  c
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the Windows `findstr` command to get rid of empty lines.

Example file "Data.txt".

```
1,a

2,b
3,c
4,a


5,b

6,c
```

Reproduces your error.

```
> dt <- fread("Data.txt")
Warning message:
In fread("Data.txt") :
Stopped reading at empty line 6 of file, but text exists afterwards (discarded): 5,b
```

But works when using Windows `findstr` directly in `fread`.

```
> require(data.table)
> dt <- fread('findstr "." Data.txt')

# > dt
#    V1 V2
# 1:  1  a
# 2:  2  b
# 3:  3  c
# 4:  4  a
# 5:  5  b
# 6:  6  c
```

Answer (score 2):

If anyone else is having a similar problem, I've noticed that data.table 1.10.4 (the current 2017 release I'm using) seems to produce empty line errors with some files if you don't explicitly state:

```
'strip.white = FALSE'
```

I was looking at what were obviously line errors in ~350 files I was trying to import. Some lines were broken across two rows in the originals and, since they contained different forms of information, fread was warning of class coercion issues for some of the columns. But I was simultaneously getting 'empty line' errors as well for almost every file, on different lines. I manually checked those in notepad++. Many times. There were no empty lines and there were remaining lines; lots of them. Tried working through the import arguments and disabling specifically strip.white removed the empty line warnings.

Comment: I'm having a very similar issue - fread is throwing a blank line error at a line index that, when I go check the file, is demonstrably false.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any universal fix. Try enabling and disabling 'fill'. That either 'fixes' some of my imports or creates other errors. All of the files causing problems have come from the FDA and should be identical. read.table usually imports them (slowly). I've tried write.table then reimport with fread, but the 'blank lines' persist. Also tried changing their quotation, delimiters, 'trimming' the tables after read.table to ensure there aren't any extra delimiters & deleting blank lines prior to write.table, adding explicit NA's & changing line endings. Error persists on fread.

Comment: blank.lines.skip option did not work for me. 
selecting specific columns to load using select option seems to work ignoring the empty lines. for example, select=c(1,2,3) loads first 3 columns and I do not get the error when I use select, fiel loads beyond the error point if i use select.

Comment: i think i observed something similar; if you select specific fields on the import it works, the problem occurs when trying to import the entire table. i never actually managed to solve why this occurs even after some fairly intensive manual checking (e.g. inspecting the line endings, removing them all, re-adding them), still got the problem. what's odd about it is r's basic 'read.table' function will work fine with the same files, suggesting it must be something to do with the error checking in fread. what it's spotting that's causing the error i've no idea at the moment.