# In R: Send a modified windows command to fread()

Tags: r, data.table

I have a large file with blank lines in it that I want to read in with fread. I used this info to assist with that: [Any way to force fread() of data.table not to stop on empty lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19895107/any-way-to-force-fread-of-data-table-not-to-stop-on-empty-lines)

This is the line that I'm using:

```
fread('findstr "." Data.txt',skip=0,sep="\n",header=FALSE)
```

However, I only want to read the most recent file in a directory.  To do that I'm doing this:

```
files <- list.files(getwd(),pattern="file_name")
newestFile <- files[length(files)]
```

How do I replace Data.txt with the name of the file I found and stored in newestFile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you already have the value stored in newestFile you can use `paste0` to construct your string

```
fread_cmd <- paste0('findstr "." ', newestFile)
fread(fread_cmd, skip = 0, sep = "\n", header = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked.  Now what if newestFile is not in my working directory?  I tried adding the full path to the file name and it didn't work.  So I resolved to changing my working directory dynamically which I'm not convinced is the best answer.