# fread a file with different EOL

Tags: r, data.table

My input file has different EOL/newline characters.
(first line ended with what appears to be `CRLF`, following lines with `CR`).

Base-R functions work fine with my file (any of `read.table()` or `scan()` or...).
From the help file of `scan()`:

> Whatever mode the connection is opened in, any of LF, CRLF or CR will be accepted as the EOL marker for a line and so will match sep = "\n".

But I have a need for data.table capabilities (multiple big files) and `fread()` seems to infer EOL from the first line only, causing following lines to be truncated at the beginning.

```
> myfile <- tempfile()
> writeLines("foo,1\r\nbar,2\rfoobar,3\r\ncoucou,4\rzut,5\nflute,6\n",
    sep = "", con = myfile)
> (with_readLines <- readLines(myfile))
[1] "foo,1"    "bar,2"    "foobar,3" "coucou,4" "zut,5"    "flute,6" 
> (with_read.table <- read.table(myfile, sep = ","))
      V1 V2
1    foo  1
2    bar  2
3 foobar  3
4 coucou  4
5    zut  5
6  flute  6
> (with_scan <- scan(myfile, sep = ",", what = list(character(), integer())))
Read 6 records
[[1]]
[1] "foo"    "bar"    "foobar" "coucou" "zut"    "flute" 

[[2]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6

> (with_fread <- data.table::fread(myfile, sep = ","))
       V1 V2
1:    foo  1
2:    bar  2
3:  oobar  3
4: coucou  4
Warning message:
In data.table::fread(myfile, sep = ",") :
  Stopped reading at empty line 5 but text exists afterwards (discarded): ut,5
flute,6
> file.remove(myfile)
[1] TRUE
```

I currently use `setDT(myDT <- read.table(myfile, sep = ","))` but am not satisfied with it. Any ideas?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.4 Revised (2016-03-16 r70336)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=fr_FR.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=fr_FR.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=fr_FR.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=fr_FR.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=fr_FR.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=fr_FR.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=fr_FR.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.9.6

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] rsconnect_0.4.1.11 tools_3.2.4        chron_2.3-47
```

Comment: If you are using windows, which I guess you are not, please find the same for ubuntu. Here is some help.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19895107/any-way-to-force-fread-of-data-table-not-to-stop-on-empty-lines