# R: Is there a way to fread data.table from file where some (irregular) lines are skipped?

Tags: r, data.table, read.table

Here's the sample data file called 'log.txt' (in reality the file contains many more lines, of course):

```
148     87      40
148     80      47
126     65      49
-
127     57      53
134     64      52
-
136     72      51
128     72      49
```

Is there a way in R/data.table, to read all lines from there?

If we run `dt <- fread("log.txt")`, we get error:

```
Error in fread("log.txt") : 
   Expected sep (' ') but new line, EOF (or other non printing character) ends field 0 when detecting types from point 0: -
```

On the other hand, if we remove all "-" and our file ("log1.txt") looks like this:

```
148     87      40
148     80      47
126     65      49

127     57      53
134     64      52

136     72      51
128     72      49
```

then, when we run  `dt <- fread("log1.txt")`, it reads only the first three lines, with warning:

```
  Warning message:
  In fread("log1.txt") :
     Stopped reading at empty line 4 but text exists afterwards (discarded): 127     57      53
```

Comment: replacing `-` with `0\t0\t0` ? (if you don't have other zeroes)

Comment: You saw this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/19895107/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Frank, 
Solution:

Step 1: Make lines that should be skipped blank (with external editor), then

Step 2: Run `fread(text, blank.lines.skip=TRUE)`